# jPlayer interferance?

Tags: css, jquery, jplayer

I have been trying to develop a website as a front end for a Audio Stream. I am working with a responsive template that uses jQuery and CSS. I am having trouble incorporating two jplayer widgets (Player & Now Playing bar) into my page. I can build a page in the same `dir` as my site and they will work. but when I try to use them in my `index.html` they do not display or function. My question is could the jquery already in my `index.html` be interfering with the scripts for jplayer? Or can it be an ordering issue, where some script refs have priority?

`/example.com/sample.html`  <---works
`/example.com/index.html`   <--does not work

**These are the jQuery references in my template**

```
bootstrap.js
bootstrap.min.js
grayscale.js
jquery.easing.min.js
jquery.js
```

Comment: You say "Could the jQuery already in my index.html be interfering..."  but then it would also interfere in `sample.html`, unless that one uses different javascript files.

Comment: The jQuery in my `index.html` such as the references. Not the files in the `/js/` dir.  Or possibly the css code in the `index.html`

Comment: I tried, but I really don't understand that comment at all.

Comment: The references to the other js files`<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>`